# Why the GIT quotient $\mathbb{A}^m//\mathbb G_{m}$ is empty?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quotient-spaces, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $\mathbb{A}^m ={\text{Spec }}\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_m]$, and the multiplicative group $\mathbb G_m \cong \mathbb{C}^*$ acts on $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_m]$ by
$$\lambda_t (x_1,\dots,x_m)= (t^{a_1}x_1,\dots,t^{a_m}x_m)$$
suppose for all $i, a_i >0$.

Then it is claimed the GIT quotient $\mathbb{A}^m//\mathbb G_{m}$ is empty, but I did not see why this is true. I am not good at GIT stuff, and I don't know why this is different from
$$\mathbb{A}^m//G_{m} = \text{Spec }\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_m]^{G_m} = \text{Spec }\mathbb{C}?$$

Comment: I am no expert on this, but I think this has to do with the fact that there are no stable points for the action. I've heard that a good reference for learning GIT is Richard Thomas's "Notes on GIT and Symplectic Reduction...."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote $A=\mathbb C[x_1, \ldots, x_m]$, $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $G=\mathbb G_m$. First, there is an affine quotient $X/G := \operatorname{Spec} \left( A^G \right)$, which in this particular case is a point.

Second, there is a GIT quotient
$$X //_{\mathcal L} G=\operatorname{Proj} \left( \bigoplus_{k \geqslant 0} H^0(X, \mathcal L^{\otimes k})^G \right),$$
which depends on the choice of $G$-linearized line bundle $\mathcal L$ on $X$. There are no non-trivial line bundles on $X=\mathbb A^m$, and $G=\mathbb G_m$ is connected, therefore $\mathcal L=\mathcal O(\chi)$ for a character $\chi: G \to \mathbb G_m$. It implies that
$$H^0 \left( X, \mathcal O(\chi^k) \right)^G=A^G_{\chi^k}:=\{ f \in A: f(gx)=\chi^k(g) f(x) \},$$
a subspace of $\chi^k$-semi-invariant functions.

- If $\chi(g)=1$ for all $g \in G$, then
  $$X //_{\mathcal O(\chi)} G=\operatorname{Proj} \left( A^G[t] \right)=\operatorname{Spec} \left( A^G \right)$$
  is an affine quotient again.
- Instead one should take $\chi(g)=g$, then
  $$X //_{\mathcal O(\chi)} G=\operatorname{Proj} A$$
  with the usual grading on $A$, that is a weighted projective space.
- More generally, if $\chi(g)=g^k$ with $k>0$, then the grading is $\deg x_i=k  \cdot a_i$, but the quotient is still a weighted projective space.
- At last, if $\chi(g)=g^k$ with $k<0$, then
  $$X //_{\mathcal O(\chi)} G=\operatorname{Proj} \left( A^G \right)$$
  is indeed empty.

For details, see [Mukai *An introduction to invariants and moduli*](https://books.google.ru/books?id=oUcMZbiM7eAC), chapter 6.1.